# Can't adjust light on Alienware AW568 keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard, alienware

I got an AW568 keyboard that has 2 RBG LED zone lights. This requires the Alienware Control Center software to manipulate the lights and is Windows compatible only.

I'm wondering what it would take to be able to adjust these lights on a Unix system (ubuntu or mac). I figure it can't be impossible.

Comment: Did you try [this post](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Alienware_13#Keyboard_lights) or [this tool](https://github.com/bchretien/AlienFxLite)?

Comment: No luck with these unfortunately